# Error 404 en ruta de edición

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

No logro dar con el error que me produce que no funcionen correctamente el código edit y destroy... 
cuando quiero modificar un registro al hacer click en el botón edit.. me trae el registro:
http://localhost/sisventas/public/categoria/12/edit
en este caso el registro es el numero doce, pero en la pagina me figura: 404
Not Found..

Estas son las rutas:

```
'`Route::get('categoria', 'CategoriaController@create') -> name('categoria.create');
Route::post('categoria', 'CategoriaController@store') -> name('categoria.store');
Route::get('categoria/edit/{id}','CategoriaController@edit')->name ('categoria.edit');
Route::post('categoria','CategoriaController@update')-> name('categoria.update');
Route::get('categoria/delete/{id}','CategoriaController@destroy')->name('categoria.delete');'
```

y el form es el siguiente:

```html
<form action=" {{url('categoria.update')}}" method="post">

@csrf
<input type="hidden" name='id' value='{{ $categoria->idcategoria}}'>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="nombre">Nombre Categoria</label>
<input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" value="{{ $categoria ->nombre}}">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="nombre">Descripcion Categoria</label>
<input type="text" name="descripcion" class="form-control" value="{{ $categoria ->descripcion}}">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Actualizar</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset"> Cancelar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

no se cual puede ser el error...

Comment: ¿Cómo estás llamando la ruta? Déjanos ver el código del enlace

Comment: Segun tu archivo de ruta la de editar seria Route::get('categoria/edit/{id}', y la que pones es categoria/12/edit, cuando deberia ser guiandonos por tu ruta: categoria/edit/12

Comment: Donde en el blade creas el botón de editar que te dirije a la ruta que pusistes arriba, pk solo veo el formulario para actualizar

Comment: <a href="{{url('categoria/'. $cat->idcategoria .'/edit')}}"><button class="btn btn-info"> Editar </button></a>
Así llamo desde la pagina..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu ruta está mal escrita, estás llamando a:

```
Route::get('categoria/edit/{id}','CategoriaController@edit')->name('categoria.edit');
```

Cuando debería de ser:

```
Route::get('categoria/{id}/edit','CategoriaController@edit')->name('categoria.edit');
```

Ahora para acceder a la url debes hacer lo siguiente en tu vista `*.blade.php`

```
{{ route('categoria.edit', $categoria->idcategoria) }}
```

Incluso una forma más simple para generar todas las rutas del CRUD. Es hacer lo siguiente:

```
Route::get('/categorias','CategoriaController')->names('categorias');
```

Y visualizar las rutas generadas en: `php artisan route:list`

Toda esta información la puedes encontrar en la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing

Comment: En el fondo esto no tiene nada que ver, sería más coherente cambiar la ruta en el enlace que en la definición.

Comment: Es cierto que la forma en como coloques tu ruta depende de cada uno, pero el problema específico es que sale un error 404 al acceder a ´http://localhost/sisventas/public/categoria/12/edit´. Entonces para que Laravel pueda hacer match a esa url. Debe modificar su ruta en el ´routes.php´.  Además la solución que brindo es la recomendación que Laravel te da en su documentación, además que cumple con el estándar de API-REST

Comment: Por lo visto conoces muy poco Laravel y las buenas prácticas, es una pésima práctica utilizar el helper url en este caso, precisamente por lo que ocurrió. -1

Comment: asi me trae ahora el formulario.. gracias.. pero ahora al hacer click para que me guarde la info modificada me sale error 404.. asi llamo a la accion update: <form action=" {{url('categoria.update')}}" method="post">

Comment: @Federico revisa mi respuesta, ahí está la solución para ambos problemas.

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta y he abarcado todo lo mencionado en estos comentarios.

Comment: al editar la ruta en edit.blade.php y ejecutar me salta el siguiente error:
return new static("Missing required parameters for [Route: {$route->getName()}] [URI: {$route->uri()}].");

Comment: @Federico debes pasarle el id de la categoría para que pueda generar la url.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name='id' value='{{ $categoria->idcategoria}}'> asi la estoy llamando para el form.. es de esta manera que debo pasarle el id? o hay otra manera?

Answer (score 2):

Según como tienes definidas las rutas en tu archivo web.php, la mejor forma de llamar la ruta es por su nombre usando el helper route():

```
{{ route('categoria.edit', $cat->idcategoria) }}
```

Para que se entienda mejor, así quedaría el código del enlace:

```
<a href="{{ route('categoria.edit', $cat->idcategoria) }}"><button class="btn btn-info"> Editar </button></a>
```

Te sugeriría utilizar Route Model Binding, para cargar el modelo directamente desde la ruta y ahorrar algo de código: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding